# Transfering PDFs to ipad on windows?

Tags: pdf, books, file-transfer

I got about 300 PDFs which I need to transfer to my iPad Mini 2 but when I press the add folder to library in iTunes on windows I am unable to get the PDF's on, I only get the .epub files up... Any idea's on how to do this without having to add them one by one? (Yes I am a book freak :P)

Comment: Have you tried iTunes?

Comment: @CousinCocaine I wrote "when I press the add folder to library in ITUNES on windows...". Yes I have tried itunes but it doesn't add PDF's into library, only epub. I can add PDFs separately ONE by ONE and I got another 200 books to add on another ipad... which just takes too much time.

Comment: Give Goodreader a try

Comment: I need an app that I can add both PDFs and epub files to, to have all books in the same place...

Comment: Apple's own iBooks can handle both...

Comment: I know that was what I used before but I am unable to add both PDFs and epub files to my iPad's iBooks via iTunes because iTunes only select epub

Comment: Strange, that is not normal behaviour. Doe you have enough storage left? Incompatible filenames? You can try GoodReader/Dropbox/etc to import to iPad, then transfer between apps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to press "Add file to library" and shift-click to select all the books... Weird that iTunes can't add PDFs with "Add folder to library".